# Taking picture without SurfaceView or without Photo Intent Activity

Tags: android, camera

I need to take a photo from phone camera to analyze it, but I do not need to show the content (image of camera) on SurfaceView. Can I use Camera class without SurfaceView holder? One way is to simply hide SurfaceView but Is there a way to not using it at all?

I tried like this but it throws an error: takePicture failed

onCreate:

```
mCamera = getCameraInstance();   //private Camera mCamera;  
mCamera.startPreview();

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

      mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

   }
});
```

Camera:

```
public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
            Camera c = null;
            try {
                c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
        }

    private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            System.out.println("CLICK");
        }
    };
```

Comment: Did you ever have any luck figuring this out? I have asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072438/how-to-take-a-picture-without-an-intent-and-without-any-view-window-in-android and I have yet to discover a solution myself.

Comment: As far as I discovered there is no other way to do it. I solve with overlay it with other view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by puting new view over the SurficeView so surficeView was not seen. I spend quite a time by searching for other solution but without success.