# How to take a picture without an Intent and without any view window in Android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, camera

Good day all, I am trying to figure out how to take a picture by pressing a button, without any preview showing up. The idea is, I want a picture to be taken and saved, but no visual preview of the photo before or afterwards. So far, I am able to get the code to take pictures and save them to the disk without any problems, but I cannot seem to do it without a surfaceview or preview.

Here is some of my code:

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        private Camera cameraObject;
        private ShowCamera showCamera;
        private Button NOPE;

        //Check if camera is avail:
        public static Camera isCameraAvailiable(){
            Camera object = null;
            try {
              object = Camera.open();
                L.m("Camera Open");
            } catch (Exception e) {
              L.m(e.toString());
            } return object; 
        }

       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          //Opens up the camera
          cameraObject = isCameraAvailiable();

          //Sets the resolution for the camera (Excluded from code here)
          setCameraResolution();

          //Button for taking photos
          NOPE = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
          NOPE.setOnClickListener(this);

          //THIS SECTION OF CODE HERE I can't get it to work without it as this creates a view/ preview for the camera
          showCamera = new ShowCamera(this, cameraObject);
          FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
          preview.addView(showCamera);
       }

        public void snapIt(View view){
           cameraObject.takePicture(null, null, new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));
       }

        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.button_capture:
                    snapIt(view);
            }
        }   
    }
```

The photo handler class:

```
public class PhotoHandler implements PictureCallback {

    private final Context context;

    public PhotoHandler(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File pictureFileDir = getDir();
        if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {
            //I removed unnecessary code here, but this is where I write to disk, which works fine.
        }
    }
```

The problem I am having is that I CANNOT actually take a photo via the camera unless I have the code about preview.addView(showCamera);.
The ShowCamera class is merely one that adds a surface view for viewing the pictures while they are being taken:

```
public class ShowCamera extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
```

Anyone have any ideas? Can this be done?

Someone asked an EXTREMELY similar question here: [Taking picture without SurfaceView or without Photo Intent Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606428/taking-picture-without-surfaceview-or-without-photo-intent-activity) , but without any success. I think I'm on a similar path as they were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem and I solve it by puting new view over the SurficeView so surficeView was not seen. I spend quite a time by searching for other solution but without success.

Comment: That makes sense, I ended up doing the same and condensing it down to 1px by 1px, which is slightly inefficient in that it still uses cpu, but it gets the job done. Thanks for the tip!